Assign B2C User to ExternalAzureAD identity
Is it possible in Azure AD B2C that I can assign a special identity (e.g. ExternalAzureAD) to a user when a user logs in? Currently all users are stored with their email as identity.
I tried searching the internet but i did't read the answer yet.

Thanks to @rbrayb I got the right sample for my needs from github here.
I just needed to add:
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingXY">
  ...
  <PersistedClaims>
    ...
    <!-- Added these lines -->
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    ...
  </PersistedClaims>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>

to my custom Technical Profile which is writing my user to Azure AD B2C.
After that my EntraId-Provider is linked with my B2C local account.

When you log in via Entra ID, you get a federated entry in the B2C Identity array.
You can add other types to this array via Graph API.
Effectively, you are linking the accounts.

Thank you for your comment! As far as I know the account-linking needs an interaction with the user where he must click on a specific button so accounts will be linked. My question refers to the situation, where employees of my company can login via the user in the entra-id app and this account is linked automatically with the local user of my b2c application. Is this possible somehow?

Right now it is just creating a local account in my b2c-directory without a link to my entra-id identity.

You will need to add the relevant social identity to the identities array; however this is derived by the sub passed in from the federated tenant - therefore, you must know what this sub will be in advance. It is easier to be reactive and do the auto-account linking during sign-in.

@bolt-io yes the thing is, that the company employees do not need a local account at all - they signup with the openIdConnect technical profile and with that signup i want to add the company-identity automatically in the background. They will never enter their email address once.

The steps should be for my employees as follows:

Click on "{Company Name}" button
SignIn with corporate identity (EntraId user)
Create local account in b2c with identity of EntraIdUser already added
Redirect to application


@rbrayb Is there a difference if the user identity is shown as "several" (i hope its the right translation) instead of "ExternalAzureAD"?

It's "Multiple". Just means that there are a number of identities linked - typically three or more.
